# Delete all iPad mail emails

Tags: ios, mail.app, ipados

Can you delete all the emails on iPad in one shot using the mail app. I can only seem to delete them 1 by 1 by pressing the trash can. Or I can go edit and select each one and then delete. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to delete it just from the iPad, then remove the account in **Settings > Mail, Contacts, & Calendars**.

You can use the Edit button to select several messages and push the Delete/Archive button to affect everything that is selected.

If you have access to a desktop machine, removing everything from the server should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

In IOS Mail App: Click Edit and there should be a "Mark All" option.   Can flag,  Mark as Read, or move to Junk.  Individually selecting mails in edit mode allows you to trash them... have to manually select though.

If it is gmail account can log in with a browser and bulk select and delete mail.

If I cloud go to https://www.icloud.com in browser.   Think you need to be on PC can select all and trash from there.

Short answer... not easily possible on IPad, but various workarounds depending on account.